# Regarding return view with model usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc. i have got a code where view is returning with model. what does it mean.
if i return view with model then model data can be access from view.

```
public ActionResult GetView(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            return View("View1", model1);
            break;
        case 2:
            return View("View2", model2);
            break;
        default:
            return View("Default", modelDefault);
    }
}
```

i need to see a small complete example where view will be return with model and view will be populated with model data. can anyone redirect me to a good example on this topic. thanks

Comment: Your code example does exactly what you want: it returns a view (a specified view in this case) and adds a model. After this the view is loaded with this model. 

What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a sample

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // return a list of movies to view
    return View(db.Movies.ToList());
}
```

**VIEW**

```
//declare expected type of model, if view returns something else, it will fail
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie> 

//use model sent from controller
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", { id=item.ID })  |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", { id=item.ID }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

More information on [Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

Comment: thanks for answer. like to know when it would be mandatory to pass model name when we return view from action method.basically i have seen people populate their model from action method and just return the view. view automatically access model data. so like to know when it would be urgent or mandatory to pass model data along with view return.